# MySQL - equivalent of SQL "Master" database that still exist?

Tags: mysql

Basically I need to connect to the database without any existing databases. In SQL, there was "master" table that still exists. I would need to create the database programatically, therefore I need to connect to the database itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL will always have a `mysql` database to store user information and other information.  There's also the `information_schema` database in later versions.

Comment: I go with `mysql`. MySQL workbench doesn't show it under "Schemas", but it is enough to connect and e.g. `create` and then `use` my actual database.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the MySQL server without specifying the database to use.

First execute `"CREATE DATABASE db"`, then `"USE db"`

Answer (score 0):

Slight confusion here perhaps. You connect to [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) and it is after you connect to MySQL that you "use" a database.

So the connection would be:

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword -hhost
```

This would make the connections regardless of actual databases on the MySQL. Obviously MySQL would need to be there and information_schema in later versions.

After that you would "use database" to use the specific database in that host.
As you are connecting programatically etc. I assume after that you will be creating a new database and then the tables/views within that. In that case you might be better off using mysqladmin to create your database remotely first.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql` and `information_schema` databases are where the server stores meta information about the database, its permissions, etc. However, you shouldn't modify these databases directly in most cases.

You can do any modification you need to using SQL, but not by editing the control databases. Instead, statements like `CREATE DATABASE x` and `GRANT perm TO user` are used to perform administrative functions.

You can connect to MySQL without connecting to any specific database within the server. In that case, any table referenced must be prefixed by their database name, but otherwise everything still works as normal.